# MVC3 Request.Form value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, null, request.form

Issue: In the controller, the Request.Form values are null and count is 0. This is happening after hosting my website with a web hosting firm. However there is no issue while I am developing the website.

**HTML PART**

```
<form action = "@ViewBag.SearchLink" method="post" style="vertical-align:middle" name="ListSearch" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<table style="width:100%;vertical-align:middle;background-color:#265A9A;border-color:Black;color:White" >
    <tr align="right"><td>
    <input id="SearchWords" name="SearchWords" type="text" style="font-size:small" maxlength="500"/>
    <select id="SearchParam" name="SearchParam" style="font-size:small">
    @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.ParamCount; i++)
    {
        if (@ViewBag.SelectedParam == @ViewBag.ParamArray[i].ParamName)
        {
            <option selected='selected' >@ViewBag.ParamArray[i].ParamName</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option>@ViewBag.ParamArray[i].ParamName</option>            
        }
    }
    </select>
    <input class="button_grad" type="submit" value=" Search Param " style="font-size:small"/>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

**CONTROLLER PART**

```
public ActionResult SearchList()
{   
    try
    {
        string searchText = string.Empty;
        if (Request.Form["SearchWords"] != null)
        {
            searchText = Request.Form["SearchWords"].ToString().TrimEnd();
            // Does not enter this if condition  
        }

        string searchParam = Request.Form["SearchParam"].ToString();
        int count = Request.Form.Count; // returns 0
```

I have looked at other links but they do not help. Am I missing anything? Please advise.

Adding the full HTML of another page which also returns Request.Form values as null.

**HTML PART**

```
@*
Author and Owner:   
Modified date:      
File Name:          Index
File Type:          CSHTML   
File Title:         Feedback
Description: 
*@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Feedback";
}

<h2>Feedback</h2>

<form name="AddFeedback" id="AddFeedback" action="@ViewBag.AddFeedbackLink" method="post" onsubmit="return Validation()" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >
<table style="width:35%">
<tr><td><label style="width:35%">Name *</label></td><td style="width:65%"><input id="Name" name="Name" maxlength="200" style="font-size:small" value="@ViewBag.FeedbackName" onchange ="ControlLeave(this)"/> <br /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label style="width:35%">Email *</label></td><td style="width:65%"><input id="EmailId" name="EmailId" maxlength="100" value="@ViewBag.EmailId" style="font-size:small"/> <br /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label style="width:35%">Contact Number</label></td><td style="width:65%"><input id="ContactNumber" name="ContactNumber" maxlength="20" style="font-size:small"/> <br /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label style="width:35%">Type *&nbsp</label></td><td style="width:65%"><select id="Type" name = "Type"><option>Advertising</option><option>Comment</option><option>Grievance</option><option>Suggestion</option></select></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Feedback Box *</label><br /></td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<textarea rows="10" cols="60"  name="Feedback" id="Feedback" style="font-size:small;background-color:#F2F2F2;"></textarea> <br /><br />
<label id="Message" style="font-size:small;color:Red">@ViewBag.FeedbackMessage</label><br /><br />
<input class="button_grad" type="submit" value=" Send "/>

</form>
```

Please advise why the above code could return Request.Form as null. 
Also please note that the website is being developed using 
*Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.*

Comment: What does `@ViewBag.SearchLink` generate in the `<form>` tag?

Comment: http://www.websitename.com/ListParams/SearchList  where ListParams is the controller name and SearchList is the method. For reference the website navigates fine to the ListParams page and does enter into the controller. I put logging in each line to find that the Request.Form lines are throwing the error "Object reference not set to ...."

Answer (score 0):

Change your conroller implematation by below things.

```
public ActionResult SearchList(FormCollection formcollection)
{   
    try
    {
        string searchText = string.Empty;
        if (formcollection["SearchWords"] != null)
        {
            searchText = formcollection["SearchWords"].ToString().TrimEnd();
            // Does not enter this if condition  
        }

        string searchParam = formcollection["SearchParam"].ToString();
```

Change Request.From to formcollection[""]

Comment: Thanks but it does not seem to have a difference i.e. the formCollection now returns null and the count is 0 for formCollection.Count. Any reason why you suggested FormCollection instead of Request.Form? Also could there be any potential configuration/setup required from the hosting service provider e.g. in IIS or web.config etc.?

Comment: Not a specific reason , you can get data in both case. only we need to make sure Submit button needs to be inside form and method="post" and action should be correct. seems like fine in your case. if you can provide complete HTML code then it will help to track more.

Comment: Jinesh Jain - I have added a complete HTML code for a Feedback page. There is some javascript code as well. I needed will post that as well.

Comment: @misra- I tried with code you mentioned and it is working fine.. it is providing me count =5  I only changed in your form tag for testing is puted hard code action="/Home/SearchList" where Home is my controller and SearchList is my action and it is working fine.

Comment: Relief. It worked for me. Will need to hard code the action in all the files or need to get to the bottom why it does not work when hosted externally. Thank you very much.